# Error when cloning a git repo with mercurial "405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Tags: git, mercurial

I'm using Win7 and mercurial (tortoise) version: 4.0 64 bit on this computer git version: 2.14.1.windows.1 64 bit is also installed.

I want to clone a git repo with mercurial, because i also have some mercurial repos I'm working with, and i don't want to use two tools. The "hggit" extension is enabled in my global mercurial.ini.
When i try to clone the repo with:

```
hg clone --verbose https://abc.def/cb/git/I-Applications-Git "C:\store\Workspace\I-Applications-Git"
```

This results in:

```
HTTP-Fehler: 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

I put the hostfingerprint in my global mercurial.ini too, becaus this was the problem i encountered before.

Comment: Assuming you're using `hggit` to access git repositories with Mercurial, you need a URL of the form `git+https://...` instead of `https://...`. See `hg help git` for details.

Comment: @Reimer: solved, thank you very much